# View more than 2 pdf pages horizontally

Tags: pdf, evince

in evince in the menu `view > dual` makes two pages appear side-by-side. Is there a way to make more pages appear horizontally? Either in evince or other.

Comment: Check answers to this question: https://superuser.com/q/1365482. Answers include evince and a simpler solution --print to pdf with mulitple pager per sheet!